# How can I solve this error of BDD-Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: D:\Cucumber_BDD\CucumberJavaD:\Cucumber_BDD\CucumberJava\src\test\resources\drivers\chromedriver.exe
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$FileStateChecker.isFile(Require.java:342)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:147)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:39)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:233)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:437)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:49)
at StepDefinitions.GoogleSearchSteps.browser_is_open(GoogleSearchSteps.java:23)
at ?.browser is open(file:///D:/Cucumber_BDD/CucumberJava/src/test/resources/Features/GoogleSearch.feature:4)

This is the code I'm using,

public class GoogleSearchSteps {

```
WebDriver driver = null;

@Given("browser is open")
public void browser_is_open() {
     System.out.println("Inside Step - browser is open");
     
     String projectPath= System.getProperty("user.dir");
     System.out.println("Project path is"+projectPath);
     
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",projectPath+"D:/Cucumber_BDD/CucumberJava/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
     
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `projectPath+"D:/Cucumber_BDD/CucumberJava/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe"` results in the path of `D:\Cucumber_BDD\CucumberJavaD:\Cucumber_BDD\CucumberJava\src\test\resources\drivers\chromedriver.exe` that looks not valid as you just concatenate two paths which originate from root `D:\`.

I am not sure why you're doing so, but if you have your executable at `D:/Cucumber_BDD/CucumberJava/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe` just use:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/Cucumber_BDD/CucumberJava/src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");`